# await/async axios call being called before response from previous call is done

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, promise

I have a React component that calls an `async` function in `componentDidUpdate`. Inside that function, I have an array of items that I call `Promise.all` on. There is one condition where an `axios` call is made depending on what gets returned from a previous `axios` call. The problem I am having is that the `axios` call is made before the results from the previous `axios` call is finished, and I am not sure why that is happening.

Here is my code:

```
class Test extends Component {
  this.state = {
    experiments: []
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.getExperiments(); // function to fetch experiments from a db
  }
  async componentDidUpdate() {
    if (condition) {
      await myFunction()
    }
  }

  myFunction = async () => {
    try {
      const { experiments } = this.state;
      const results = await Promise.all(experiments.map(async experiment => {
        const firstAxiosCall = await axios.get(someUrl);
        const secondAxiosCall = await axios.get(anotherUrl)
        const { data } = secondAxiosCall; // THIS IS WHERE BUG OCCURS
        if (data.length === 0) {  // For one experiment, this is not empty, but it still goes into the if statement.
          await axios.post(thirdUrl)
        }
      }));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('ERROR', e);
    }
  }
}
```

I know that this is a bug because the `axios` call inside the if statement is called and I get a db error on my backend saying that nothing was passed in. I want the data from the second axios call to return first before proceeding the if statement. Is there something that I am doing wrong?

I hope this is enough information!

Thank you all!

Comment: `map()` doesn't wait for promises to resolve before moving to the next iteration.  I would suggest using a library like `bluebird` to deal with async collection methods

Comment: The way your code is written there, `firstAxiosCall` should happen, and then `secondAxiosCall`, ahd then the `{data}` line, and then the `if`. You're awaiting everything properly. I suspect your problem is different than what you've described

Comment: Try `const { data } = await secondAxiosCall;`. I'm not sure if this will work but it doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: Just use a regular `for` loop instead of `.map()`.  Then, the loop will sequence properly with your `await`.  As has already been said, `.map()` doesn't pause for an `await` inside its callback, it just keeps doing to the next iteration of the  loop while the callback is stuck at the `await`.  I suspect that your pseudo-code isn't really showing us enough of the rest of your question because the real problem is probably in the actual details that you aren't showing us.

Comment: @jfriend00 I thought regular `for` loops didnt `await` either (unless using `for(x in y)`)?

Comment: @MichaelOssig - Regular `for` loops do `await` (all types of `for` loops).  That's a hugely useful feature.  `.forEach()`, `.map()`, `.filter()` don't.  But, regular `for` loops do.

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah thats great to know.  I've been using `bluebird` for a while now since it used to be way more efficient than native V8, but any time I can cut a package is good by me

Comment: @MichaelOssig - Bluebird's concurrency feature in `.map()` is still really useful.  But, I don't find I need it for much beyond that any more.  I'd like to see Javascript add some promise-aware array iteration.  The foundation is there with asyncIterators now.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use something like so:

```
myFunction = async () => {
await axios.all([
    axios.get('http://someurl.com'),
    axios.get('http://anotherurl.com')
  ])
  .then(axios.spread((someUrlRest, anotherUrlRes) => {
    // do something with both responses
  });
}
```